# Can python decimal preserve decimal formatting

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, precision, decimalformat

Python decimal module is converting an exact encoded string decimal value into e notation, which is rather unexpected given the module documentation.

```
>>> d = decimal.Decimal('0.00000039')
>>> d
Decimal('3.9E-7')
```

Also after trying to quantize the value the output stays the same:

```
>>> print d.quantize(decimal.Decimal('0.00000001'))
3.9E-7
```

How can I prevent this from happening and just keep the source formatting without having to do format conversions. Please also feel free to recommend other stable and reliable modules for working with exact decimals.

Comment: It is important to note that `Decimal('0.00000039')` is exactly the same value as `Decimal('3.9E-7')`.

Answer (score 2):

You have full control over how the value is displayed, using either `'%f'` or `{:f}` string formatting instructions. For example:

```
>>> d = decimal.Decimal('.0000000037')
>>> print('{:f}'.format(d))
0.0000000037
>>> print('{:e}'.format(d))
3.7e-9
>>> print('{:g}'.format(d))
3.7e-9
>>>
```

Here are other ways to display the value:

```
In [4]: d = decimal.Decimal('.0000000037')

In [5]: d
Out[5]: Decimal('3.7E-9')

In [6]: str(d)
Out[6]: '3.7E-9'

In [7]: repr(d)
Out[7]: "Decimal('3.7E-9')"

In [8]: '{:f}'.format(d)
Out[8]: '0.0000000037'
```

If you want to customize the default representations of `Decimal`, you can derive a class from `decimal.Decimal` and override `.__str__()` and `.__repr__`.

```
import decimal

class Decimal(decimal.Decimal):
    def __str__(self):
        return "'" + decimal.Decimal.__format__(self, 'f') + "'"
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Usage:

```
>>> import x
>>> d = x.Decimal('0.0000000039')
>>> d
'0.0000000039'
>>> [d]
['0.0000000039']
```

Note that this will always use your specified formatting style, even if the original text was in a different format.

```
>>> e = x.Decimal('6.022140857e23')
>>> e
'602214085700000000000000'
>>> [e]
['602214085700000000000000']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, I am aware that I can control output with format, just that I expected not having to do it with a module that advertises as 'school-like' decimal arithmetic, so it's somewhat unexpected. If you know a way of forcing notation on a module level that would be more than helpful.

Comment: If you know that you can control the output, then I'm confused about your question. Are you saying that you don't like the result of `str(d)`? That is, you don't like the result that the REPL prints?

Comment: Yes, the expectation is that it would not change the formatting of string constructed values, REPL or otherwise.

Comment: That's not how `Decimal` works. On construction, the argument is  converted to a precise numeric form. The original formatting is immediately discarded. If you always want `%f` formatting, you could derive your own class from `Decimal` and override `.__str__` and `.__repr__`. But that will always be `%f`, even if the original string was in scientific notation.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer, I guess there is no way of implicitly preserving formatting with Decimal.